# Axios in loop execution

Tags: loops, if-statement, axios

Currently I am stuck at coding which is the output should be in proper sequence. I have loop, if-statement and Axios call in it. The code is something like these.

```
var job = [[obj1.Clean], [obj2.Wash], [obj3.Clean]];
for (i = 0; i < job.length; i++) {
  if (job.task == "Clean") {
    console.log("Clean");
    clean();
  } else if (job.task == "Wash") {
    console.log("Wash");
    wash();
  }
}

async function clean() {
  //await Axios 1 here
}

async function wash() {
  //await Axios 2 here
}
```

What makes wonder is the output appears as following:

```
Clean
Wash
Clean
[output axios 1]
[output axios 2]
[output axios 1]
```

Thus what should I do in order to obtain such sequence?

```
Clean
[output axios 1]
Wash
[output axios 2]   
Clean
[output axios 1]
```

p/s: the best documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie, read with caution.

Use `for...of` loop instead to work with an `async` function. `forEach` and `for` statements will fire all without waiting:

```
async function doJob () {    
for (j of job) {
    if (j.task == "Clean") {
        console.log("Clean");
        await clean();
      } else if (j.task == "Wash") {
        console.log("Wash");
        await wash();
    }
}
```

I refer to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). Btw, in case you have more steps, maybe a `switch` statement would suit your purpose better than an `if-else` statement because you're using `string` instead of `boolean` according to this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/#:%7E:text=A%20switch%20statement%20is%20usually,a%20set%20of%20nested%20ifs.&text=if%2Delse%20better%20for%20boolean,great%20for%20fixed%20data%20values.). This [one](https://thecodebarbarian.com/for-vs-for-each-vs-for-in-vs-for-of-in-javascript) is also a good read on `for` statements.

Comment: Terima kasih atas pertolongan ini. :)